# Linearly Depndent Subset in a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, vectors

If a subset S in a vector space V is linearly dependent & $T \in$ *L(V, W)*, then T(S) is linearly
dependent in $W$.

Is $L(V, W)$ the linear combination of two spaces V and W? If so, what is T(S)? I am having some trouble on getting started on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

$L(V,W)$ is the set of linear transformations from $V$ to $W$.

So basically they are telling us $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$.

So if $v$ is a vector in $V$ $T(v)$ is a vector in $W$.

In this case $T(S)$ is the image of the set $S$ under the transform.